# Jquery Library souce code of $.grep ..!

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)

Jquery Library souce code of $.grep.....

grep: function( elems, callback, inv ) {

```
    var retVal,
        ret = [],
        i = 0,
        length = elems.length;
    inv = !!inv;

    // Go through the array, only saving the items
    // that pass the validator function
    for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
        retVal = !!callback( elems[ i ], i );
        if ( inv !== retVal ) {
            ret.push( elems[ i ] );
        }
    }

    return ret;
},
```

In this example above is jquery grep on souce code of jquery library. Why he make inv as default is undefined and he changed to boolean and same thing **retVal** store the **!!callback** and change to the boolean.
The issue is how if statement Works...?? Can give me some more details explanation..!! Thanks.

```
        retVal = !!callback( elems[ i ], i );
        if ( inv !== retVal ) {
            ret.push( elems[ i ] );
        }
```

Comment: For !!, check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript and for !== Check these : http://www.c-point.com/javascript_tutorial/jsgrpComparison.htm and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use

Answer (score 1):

`!` is a unary operator that coerces the operand to a boolean and then returns the opposite. put two of them together (`!!`) and you get an operand coerced to a boolean and double negated - it's boolean representation. most people prefer `Boolean(val)` to `!!val` since it's much easier to understand.

```
// this calls "callback" and converts the return value to a boolean
retVal = !!callback( elems[ i ], i );
// if the converted return value is not identical to "inv" then... 
if ( inv !== retVal ) {
    // elems[i] is pushed on to the top of the array "ret"
    ret.push( elems[ i ] );
}
```

Note that the condition `inv !== retVal` could also be written `inv != retVal` since we know both `inv` and `retVal` are boolean types, but it is a good habit to always use identity operators even when a comparison operator would do.